# Are fields and screenshots of the primary language used when no localized versions are provided?

Tags: localization, app-store-connect

The app has various localizations in iTunes Connect.

If no text is provided for specific field of a localization, e.g. field "Keywords", will the field value of the primary language be provided? 
And is the same true for the screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple localizations for your app in iTunes Connect, you **must** enter/provide the minimal information/number of screenshots to be able to submit your app for review.

- In case of **metadata** (keywords, description, app name, etc.): App name, description, keyword, what's new (for update) and support URL are required.
- In case of **screenshots**: You have to provide at least one screenshot per required device category. If you add a new localization, iTunes Connect takes the screenshots from your main locale

For what kind of information are required and when you can edit them got to the Developer Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1